# Using exported symbols

Tags: haskell, module

I have a Haskell file called maxflow.hs  that exports few symbols

```
module MaxFlow 
(solveMaxFlow,MaxFlowNet,Vertex,Graph) where
import Data.List 


data Vertex = Vertex {
                          vertexLabel :: String
                        , vertexNeighbors :: [(String,Int)]
                        , vertexDistance :: Int
                        , vertexPredecessor :: String
                      } deriving (Show)

....
```

In the same directory I have another file called elimination.hs  that tries to use one of those symbols

```
import MaxFlow

g =  [
                Vertex "0" [("1",16), ("2",13)         ] (maxBound::Int)  "",
                Vertex "1" [("2",10), ("3",12)  ] (maxBound::Int) "",
                Vertex "2" [("4",14) ,("1",4)        ] (maxBound::Int) ""    ,
                Vertex "3" [ ("5",20), ("2",9)] (maxBound::Int) ""      ,
                Vertex "4" [("5",4), ("3",7) ] (maxBound::Int) ""      ,
                Vertex "5" [ ] (maxBound::Int) ""    
      ]
```

But for some reason I can't load this file. Running 
**:l  elimination.hs**

I get

```
elimination.hs:4:17: error:
    Data constructor not in scope:
      Vertex :: [Char] -> [([Char], Integer)] -> Int -> [Char] -> a
  |
4 |                 Vertex "0" [("1",16), ("2",13)         ] (maxBound::Int)  "",
  |                 ^^^^^^
```

I'm probably missing something very basic. Any idea ?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module MaxFlow 
   (...,Vertex,...) where
```

This says you want to export the **type** named `Vertex` and not the **data constructor** or the fields.  What you probably want is either to export both the data type and the data constructor:

```
module MaxFlow (Vertex(Vertex)) where
```

Or to export the type, all data constructors, and all fields:

```
module MaxFlow (Vertex(..)) where
```

Those dots are literal not a short hand, you can type `Vertex(..)` in the export list to mean the type, data constructors, and all fields.

Answer (score 3):

You only exported the type constructor, not its data constructor(s). If you want to export the data constructor(s), you can write the can write this between parenthesis in the export:

```
module MaxFlow (solveMaxFlow, MaxFlowNet, Vertex(Vertex), Graph) where

-- …
```

If you want to export the getters/setters, you should include these in the parenthesis as well:

```
module MaxFlow (solveMaxFlow, MaxFlowNet, Vertex(Vertex, vertexLabel, vertexNeighbors, vertexDistance, vertexPredecessor), Graph) where

-- …
```

You can write two consecutive dots (`..`) if you want to export all:

```
module MaxFlow (solveMaxFlow, MaxFlowNet, Vertex(..), Graph) where

-- …
```